# Numpy.savetxt formatting issue: adding a string column

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, string-formatting

I've narrowed my issue down to the following:

```
import numpy as np

out_file = "results.txt"
results = [[1,2,3,.4,"5"]] # just one row for testing
format = ['%i', '%i', '%i', '%f', '%s']

np.savetxt(out_file, results, format, '\t')
```

I'm just trying to save 5 columns of data: 3 ints, 1 float, and a string. When I attempt to so, I receive the error:

```
File ".\npyio.py", line 1391, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U32') and format specifier ('%i      %i      %i      %f      %s')
```

The code works just fine if I remove the string format and the corresponding value in the array.

This *feels* like one of those times that I'm just doing something really stupid, but after a couple hours of fruitless googling I think I need help.

Comment: `results` is turned into an array before saving. Try that yourself to see what the formatting has to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal numpy arrays have one datatype only. You could initialize the array with the `dtype='O'` Object type but it stil wouldn't work with `savetxt()`.

The solution to your problem is a structured array as shown [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html).

Comment: Why is that I'm able to use %i and %f together without any issue? Or is my entire array being coerced into floats so that I can have that one float column?

Comment: Also, I found this link really helpful for building a structured array: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html